# Decode sessiondata of Django user which is encoded into base64 in Lua

Tags: python, django, lua

I am using redis with Lua to fetch `sessiondata` of any admin from Django project .In Django project `sessiondata` is encoded into base64 form.
sessiondata  value is :

```
session_data = "NzlmZjZmNWQxMGIzNTQzMDZhNDZjNzJiZGQ4OWZiY2NjNDg0NDVlZTqAAn1xAShVEl9hdXRoX3VzZXJfYmFja2VuZHECVSlkamFuZ28uY29udHJpYi5hdXRoLmJhY2tlbmRzLk1vZGVsQmFja2VuZHEDVQ1fYXV0aF91c2VyX2lkcQSKAgEKdS4="
```

My Lua code to decode session data is

```
-- decode base64 code fetch from django session data
local b='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
local function dec(data)
    data = string.gsub(data, '[^'..b..'=]', '')
    return (data:gsub('.', function(x)
        if (x == '=') then return '' end
        local r,f='',(b:find(x)-1)
       for i=6,1,-1 do r=r..(f%2^i-f%2^(i-1)>0 and '1' or '0') end
        return r;
    end):gsub('%d%d%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?', function(x)
        if (#x ~= 8) then return '' end
        local c=0
        for i=1,8 do c=c+(x:sub(i,i)=='1' and 2^(8-i) or 0) end
        return string.char(c)
    end))
end
```

when I am running `print(dec(session_data))` I am getting

```
output = 79ff6f5d10b354306a46c72bdd89fbccc48445ee:�}q(U_auth_user_backendqU)django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackendqU _auth_user_idq� u.
```

while output suppose to be

```
{'_auth_user_id': 2561L, '_auth_user_backend': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'}
```

like Django we had.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong .

Comment: Running `base64 -D` on your data gives me the same output. Running `base64` on your desired output gives me nothing even close to the data.

Comment: @lhf  base64 -D   ???? can you explain i am not getting it

Comment: `base64` is a command-line utility in Mac OS X. There's probably a version you can use in your platform.

Comment: actually i am working with ubuntu so is there any way to do this on ubuntu systm.

Comment: Try `base64 -d` in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search yields [this blog post](http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=920).

This is the (abridged, nonverifying) python code he has to do the decoding of sessiondata:

```
def decode(session_data, secret_key, class_name='SessionStore'):
    encoded_data = base64.b64decode(session_data)
    utoken, pickled = encoded_data.split(b':', 1)
    return pickle.loads(pickled)
```

In other words, your expectations are wrong. The un-base64-ed data contains a checksum hash (`79ff6...445ee`) followed by a `:` followed by serialized (via pickle) python data (`�}q(U_auth..._user_idq� u.`).

If you really want to understand how to decode python picked data, see [PEP 307](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0307/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django 1.5.3+ you can use [json serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization) so that you don't have to try to decode python pickles in lua ;) Json serializer is default in django 1.6+.